# Meaning of "By way of information"

Tags: formal-language, terminology

> "By way of information"

What does it mean? Is it correct for a formal letter?

Comment: I assume you've found this somewhere, if you can copy the expression but you don't know what it means. It would be better if you could provide more context, and tell us where you saw this. See our [_Details, please_... meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more helpful tips on asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way of saying **take note**, or **you should know** or **you should be aware** of the following information.

It's used in all kinds of formal and semi-formal communications but would sound odd between friends.

So an agency might well say:

> By way of information, the airline offices will be closed next Friday but your reservation will still be accessible online.

Informally, you might tell a friend.

> By the way, the airline offices. etc.....

It's fine for a formal letter but might sound a bit presumptuous from an applicant to a company or university.

Comment: "For information purposes" could be an equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

It's a formal equivalent of "FYI" (for your information)